# common authentication logic in asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net

I m newb in asp.net. I m working for an example with Membership class in ASP.NET. I have some pages in my project e.g. default.aspx, page1.aspx, page2.aspx. I  have put login control in default.aspx. Now I want to check authentication of user when user want to access any page. Already I achieved this thing to put below snippest in Page_Load event in every Page. But want some suggestion so that i can remove this duplicate code from every page. and implemete some logic which can be applicable on every page. Do i need to use global.asax or any class which could be inherite in all page an check authentication?

```
if(!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
Response.redirect("default.aspx");

        }
```

Comment: Have a look at these tutorials: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx ... http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication . Here's a simple but complete one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up your default login page from the authentication element of the web.config file in the root of your asp.net application.

an example...

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           name=".ASPXAUTH" 
           path="/"
           defaultUrl="default.aspx"
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
```

Controlling access to files and folders is done via the authorisation element.

an example...

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin" />
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) for full details and more examples.

Comment: okay.. It is working properly with my code. 
first of all thank you very much.
but What should I do when I need to allow to access the page for some specific users having admin or such kind role.?

Comment: you can specify roles in the authorization element, have updated the example for you.

Answer (score 0):

In .net, you can set this within the web.config using the `authorization` element.

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This will deny all users, who are not authenticated, access to any other page apart from the Login page which you specify in the `authentication` element.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
       protection="All"
       timeout="30"
       name=".ASPXAUTH" 
       path="/"
       requireSSL="false"
       slidingExpiration="true"
       defaultUrl="default.aspx"
       cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
       enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

As taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

Comment: okay.. It is working properly with my code. first of all thank you very much. but What should I do when I need to allow to access the page for some specific users having admin or such kind role.?

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of the authorization, Baldy is correct.

For any other code that you may not want to duplicate per page, you may want to place it in a masterpage to which all of your pages belong.

Masterpages:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx